# How to Pass an int array and a List<string> as argument to C++ from C# when using SWIG

Tags: c#, c++, swig

Using SWIG I need to pass a List and int array to a C++ function as arguments. I tried with below code

'''***CPP Interface code***

```
%module (directors="1") CppTestApp


%{
    #include "TestClass.h"

    #include "TestDataClass.h"
%}


 %include <windows.i>
 %include <std_list.i>
 %include <std_string.i>
 %include "arrays_csharp.i"

%feature("director") Base;

%include "TestClass.h"
%include "TestDataClass.h"
```

'''

But I am getting the arguments as **SWIGTYPE_p_std__listT_std__string_t** & **SWIGTYPE_p_double** I am not able to assign List to the above variable. Can someone help to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer for How to pass array from C# to C++ using swig. Please see it below

''' SWIG Interface code

```
%module (directors="1") CppTestApp

%{
    #include "TestClass.h"

    #include "TestDataClass.h"
%}

%include <windows.i>
%include <std_string.i>

%include <arrays_csharp.i>
CSHARP_ARRAYS(char *, string)

%typemap(imtype, inattributes="[In, global::System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex=0, ArraySubType=UnmanagedType.LPStr)]") char * INPUT[] "string[]"

%apply char * INPUT[]  { char * argv  [], char * argvqq  [] }
%apply int INPUT[]  { int sourceArray [] }
%apply double INPUT[]  { double sourcedoubleArray [] }
%apply char INPUT[]  { char chArray [] }
%apply bool INPUT[]  { bool bArray [] }
%apply long INPUT[]  { long lArray [] }
%apply float INPUT[]  { float fArray [] }

%feature("director") Base;

%include "TestClass.h"
%include "TestDataClass.h"
```

'''

'''C++ Code

```
class TestClass
{
public:

    int times2(int sourceArray[], double sourcedoubleArray[], char* argv[], char chArray[], bool bArray[], float fArray[], long lArray[]);

};
```

'''

''' Generated SWIG C# code

```
[global::System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("CppTestApp", EntryPoint="CSharp_TestClass_times2")]
  public static extern int TestClass_times2(global::System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef jarg1, [global::System.Runtime.InteropServices.In, global::System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(global::System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.LPArray)]int[] jarg2, [global::System.Runtime.InteropServices.In, global::System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(global::System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.LPArray)]double[] jarg3, [In, global::System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex=0, ArraySubType=UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string[] jarg4, string jarg5, [global::System.Runtime.InteropServices.In, global::System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(global::System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.LPArray,ArraySubType=System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.I1)]bool[] jarg6, [global::System.Runtime.InteropServices.In, global::System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(global::System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.LPArray)]float[] jarg7, [global::System.Runtime.InteropServices.In, global::System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(global::System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.LPArray)]int[] jarg8);
```

'''